# How do I pivot a joined table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, pivot-table

I have a table 
senators:
    sname (key) 
    party     <--can be Democrat or Republican

thats joined by table 
sponsors:
    sname (fk)
    legnum

I want to create a table thats formatted like this:

```
 |Democrat |  Republican | legnum  |
 |Clinton  |   McCain    |  1234   |
```

****Basically I need to create a table using the list of senators and put two candidates (one from each party) that is sponsoring a bill (legnum). How do I do this in postresql? *****

```
SELECT Democrat, Republican, legnum
FROM
     (select distinct sname, legnum, ROW_NUMBER() over
     (Partition By sname Order By sname) as ColumnSequence 
     from senators
     inner join sponsors
     on sponsors.sname = senators.sname)
pivot
( 
     max(sname)
     for ColumnSequence in (Democrat, Republican))
 )PIV;
```

The above is a query I wrote that doesn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select sp.legnum,
       max(case when se.party = 'D' then se.name end) as Democrat,
       max(case when se.party = 'R' then se.name end) as Republican
from senators se join
     sponsors sp
     on sp.sname = se.sname
group by sp.legnum;
```

You can use `array_agg()` or `string_agg()` if you want a list of all the sponsors, by party.